# Форматирование дерева таблицей

Tags: html, css, jstree

Есть дерево такого типа

```css
.tree {
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaff;
}
.level {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="node">
      <span class="name">Name 1</span>
      <span class="value">Value</span>
    </div>
    <div class="level">
      <div class="node">
        <span class="name">Name 1.1</span>
        <span class="value">Value</span>
      </div>
      <div class="level">
        <div class="node">
          <span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span>
          <span class="value">Value</span>
        </div>
        <div class="level">
          <div class="node">
            <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
            <span class="value">Value</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="level">
        <div class="node">
          <span class="name">Name 1.1.2</span>
          <span class="value">Value</span>
        </div>
        <div class="level">
          <div class="node">
            <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
            <span class="value">Value</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я хочу, чтобы в дереве все `<span class="value">` отображались в столбик справа, а длинные `<span class="name">` переносились на несколько строк.

Т.е. хочется вот так

```
Name 1               Value
  Name 1.1           Value
    Name 1.1.1       Value
      Long long long Value
      name
    Name 1.1.2       Value
      Long long long Value
      name
```

При этом разметкой и стилями дерева я не управляю и мне они неизвестны.

Я могу модифицировать только класс `tree` и стили и наполнение элементов `<div class="node">`. Собственно эти элементы я создаю сам. А все дерево - сторонняя библиотека

**Update**

@[Vladimir Rodichev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321559/) подсказал решение, но к сожалению `justify-content: space-between;` не помогает. Т.к., как оказалось, библиотека вставляет блоки в узлы с `display: inline-block;`. Если переопределить у себя

```css
.anchor {
  display: inline;
}
```

то плывет отрисовка узлов

**Update 2**

Т.к. все советы не работают для моей задачи, то привожу конкретную задачу.

Дерево отрисовывается при помощи библиотеки [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/)

Эта библиотека добавляет свои узлы со своими стилями

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#tree").jstree();
  $("#tree").jstree("open_all");
});
```

```css
.tree {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #eaeaff;
}

.node {
  display: inline;
}
.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.2/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree" class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="node">
        <span class="name">Name 1</span>
        <span class="value">Value</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="node">
            <span class="name">Name 1.1</span>
            <span class="value">Value</span>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="node">
                <span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span>
                <span class="value">Value</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="node">
                    <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
                    <span class="value">Value</span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="node">
                <span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span>
                <span class="value">Value</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="node">
                    <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
                    <span class="value">Value</span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Или полностью рантайм

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  const data = {
    text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
    children: [{
      text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
      children: [{
        text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
        children: [{
          text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name Long Long Name</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
        }, {
          text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.2.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
          children: [{
            text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name Long Long Name</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };

  $("#tree").on("load_node.jstree", function() {
    $("#tree").jstree("open_all");
  }).jstree({
    core: {
      data: data
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tree {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #eaeaff;
}

.node {
  display: inline;
}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.2/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree" class="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 2:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  const data = {
    text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
    children: [{
      text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
      children: [{
        text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
        children: [{
          text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name Long Long Name</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
        }, {
          text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name 1.2.1</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
          children: [{
            text: '<div class="node"><span class="name">Name Long Long Name</span><span class="value">Value</span></div>',
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };

  $("#tree").on("load_node.jstree", function() {
    $("#tree").jstree("open_all");
  }).jstree({
    core: {
      data: data
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tree {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #eaeaff;
}

.node {
  display: inline;
}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}


.name {
    white-space: normal;
}
.node {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    /* width: calc(100% - 51px); */
}
a.jstree-anchor {
    width: calc(100% - 24px);
    height: auto !important;
    /* width: 100%; */
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jstree-default .jstree-hovered {
    background: #90caf9 !important;
}
.jstree-default .jstree-clicked {
    background: #2196f3 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.2/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree" class="tree"></div>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо вам большое. Один вопрос - зачем вы переопределяете стили для `.jstree-default`? У меня, вроде, и без них все подкрашивается правильно.  Или это из-за общего фона дерева?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Я изменил цвет подкрашивания для себя, визуально лично для меня его лучше видно. Забыл стереть. Если вам нужна оригинальная подсветка, то просто сотрите два стиля в CSS внизу.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в CSS:

```
.node {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.anchor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Или принудительно меняем свойство:

```
.anchor {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```css
.tree {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eaeaff;
}

.level {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.value {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.anchor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.node {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div class="level">
    <a class="anchor">
      <div class="node">
        <span class="name">Name 1</span>
        <span class="value">Value</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="level">
      <a class="anchor">
        <div class="node">
          <span class="name">Name 1.1</span>
          <span class="value">Value</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="level">
        <a class="anchor">
          <div class="node">
            <span class="name">Name 1.1.1</span>
            <span class="value">Value</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="level">
          <a class="anchor">
            <div class="node">
              <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
              <span class="value">Value</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="level">
        <a class="anchor">
          <div class="node">
            <span class="name">Name 1.1.2</span>
            <span class="value">Value</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="level">
          <a class="anchor">
            <div class="node">
              <span class="name">Long long long name</span>
              <span class="value">Value</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает отлично для исходного вопроса. Но не работает в коде. Оказалось, что узлы вкладываются в `inline-block`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Непонятно. Покажите код тот, где должно работать как надо.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Я отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Не работает. Там перед `anchor` стоит еще иконка. Из-за чего `width: 100%;` приводит к уползанию правого края за границы всего дерева. Я вижу, что в общем виде задача не решается. Завтра опубликую конкретный мой пример с моей библиотекой

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Да, так будет лучше. Тогда на конкретном примере, решим. Если успею я.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov второй ответ.